# Display an image with height 'matchparent' and also keep the aspectratio

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I want to display an image in Imageview with full height and also keep the aspect ratio of the image. To view the remaining part of the image, I want horizontal scrolling on that image. Please share the idea behind it?

[image][image]

Comment: so you have to use `HorizontalScrollView` with `ImageView` as a child

Comment: HorizontalScrollview didn't allow me to keep the aspect ratio

Comment: because it is child view (`ImageView`) responsibility to specify its size correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [ResolutioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5633418/resolution), `adjustViewBounds` does the trick, but `fitXY` is not necessary. Just wrap your `ImageView` inside a `HorizontalScrollView`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine adjustViewBound and scaleType="fitXY" to achieve your goal. This will keep the aspect ratio of the image. Like this:

```
<ImageView
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: didn't keep the aspect ratio

Comment: Didn't you try it? It will keep if combine with android:adjustViewBounds

Comment: a hint: see [setAdjustViewBounds](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java#350) - now, do you see that `fitXY` has nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```